# How do I upgrade rspec to a specific version in my Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, upgrade, rspec-rails

I’m using Rails 4.2.10.  I have the following version of spec …

```
$ bin/rspec --version
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:200: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
3.4.4
```

In my Gemfile, I have

```
rspec (3.4.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
…
rspec-rails (3.4.2)
  actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
  activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
  railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
  rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
rspec-support (3.4.1)
```

How do I upgrade spec to a specific version (I want 3.10.0).  I tried changing my Gemfile.lock version to look like

```
rspec (3.10.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
```

And then re-ran “bundle install”, but I still show “3.4.4” when I check the version of bin/rspec.

**Edit:** In response to answer given in comment ...

Tried changing my Gemfile “spec-rails” dependency to

gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.9.1'

And then running the below but I guess there are a series of dependencies that result in things like the below

```
$ bundle install
…
deprecated
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies........
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rspec-support":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rspec-support (= 3.4.1)

  In Gemfile:
    guard-rspec was resolved to 4.6.4, which depends on
      rspec (>= 2.99.0, < 4.0) was resolved to 3.10.0, which depends on
        rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0) was resolved to 3.4.1, which depends on
          rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.9.1) was resolved to 3.9.1, which depends on
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Not quite sure how to proceed with the upgrade.

Comment: you only need to specify `rspec-rails` in Gemfile, nothing else, remove all other references to rspec from Gemfile. In Gemfile specify `rspec-rails '3.10.0'`. Run `bundle update rspec-rails`, you should never edit Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Edited my question to include output in response to your suggestion.

Comment: assuming you have followed my previous suggestions, and the changes you made are NOT as you've shown in your post (I think you've shown Gemfile.lock iso Gemfile in your post). Then delete Gemfile.lock and run bundle install.

Comment: Can you share Gemfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade all gems that are mentioned and might collide with their required RSpec-version. The output tells you, that guard-rspec collides with a newer RSpec-version. Try with:

```
bundle update rspec rspec-rails guard-rspec
```

If then there is another error with new Gems, try adding those to the command, too. Transitive dependencies, that are not listed in your Gemfile are generally not required to list (rspec-mocks etc.).

Summary: Try upgrading all related offending Gems at once.

Also, as Les said, you are not supposed to update Gemfile.lock manually (except in case of Merge Conflicts), but only through `bundle update [GEMNAME]`.

Deleting Gemfile.lock is a last resort, as you will lose your current, maybe well-functioning, dependency situation and upgrade all Gems at once to their newest version, as specified in the Gemfile.

Comment: By running the above (bundle update rspec rspec-rails guard-rspec), what version am I upgrading things to?  I don't want to upgrade rspec to 4 or above, but do want to upgrade it above 3.4.4, where it is now.

Comment: It will update to latest version allowed by your Gemfile constraints ( 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.9.1').